# Скопировать исходный код html стороннего домена js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Как скопировать html код страницы стороннего домена средствами js, jQuery, ajax и прочими веб языками которые исполняются на стороне клиента?

PHP и остальные серверные языки здесь не подходят.

Comment: И главное, зачем?

Comment: Ну можно просто вывести на экран, не суть. Нужно скопировать код клиентскими средствами

Comment: Зачем копировать код со страницы и выводить на экран, если он и так выводится у пользователя на экран в браузере?

Comment: я к примеру сказал=) мне нужно получить html код...суть в том что штмл нужно получить через выше указанные языки ну или что-то иное, но на стороне юзера

Comment: `console.log(document.querySelector('html').outerHTML);` после `document.ready`. [Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/wx15qhj5/).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но это немного не то...мне нужно получить код стороннего сайта. Я вроде указал выше

Comment: Почитайте про `AJAX Cross Origin`. Вроде, это то, что Вам требуется.

Answer (score 5):

Получить скриптом из одного домена содержание из другого в общем случае **нельзя** – это запрещает политика безопасности браузеров ([Правило ограничения домена](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0)).

**Почему:** представьте, страница интернет-банка. Направив туда пользователя через iFrame на вашем «зловредном» сайте, не будь ограничения домена, вы смогли бы читать всю конфиденциальную информацию о состоянии счетов посетителя. Т.е. уже *ваш* JS получил бы html банка, и делал с ним что-то, о чём банк не в курсе – например, слал на ваш сервер.

Есть [обходные пути](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), для которых нужна кооперация обеих сторон. Но если «владельцы» контента ничего не предприняли для того, чтобы вы могли загружать их html у себя – ничего не выйдет.

**Ещё вариант обхода** – поднять на своём домене прокси, и получать контент *будто бы* со своего домена: `moj_sajt.ru/proxy/www.google.com`

Comment: ну ток это не зловредный сайт:) но суть проблемы лежала в том, что код надо было исполнять на клиентской части

Comment: Чет в итоге не получилось спарсить код iframe стороннего ресурса. Есть еще какие нибудь варианты? :(

Comment: @Corle, так оно и не должно было получится. Читайте ответ внимательнее!

Comment: прекрасный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Если сторонний домен принадлежит вам или есть доступ к серверу то вам поможет заголовок `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` ([CORS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)). Статья на [Хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/114432/)